# Textfield () - how to prevent mouse right click menu

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

Textfield ()  -   how to prevent mouse right click menu from appearing  (a menu having COPY, PASTE, SELECT ALL etc options).

Comment: If you want answers for specific situations you will have to specify them in your question.

Comment: I FOUND A WAY!!!! check my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FlashPlayers default menu items.**

As far as I know you **cannot** remove the basic FlashPlayer items (Settings and About) which make sense.

**FlashPlayers inbuilt items**

You can remove the top ones (Play, Pause, etc.) by either specifying it while compiling or from within the code:

```
contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
```

or within the global context :

```
stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
```

**TextField related menu items**

The copy/paste/select being inbuilt as well for TextFields it doesn't seem you can hide them. However as it seems like you really want to get rid of them here's a **workaround**.
The example below illustrates how you can add a transparent button over the textField to sidetrack the mouse behavior:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.ui.ContextMenu;        


    public class TestText extends Sprite 
    {

        private var textField:TextField;

        public function TestText()
        {
            // Removes the inbuit items from the contextMenu

            var contextMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            contextMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
            this.contextMenu = contextMenu;

            // Adds a simple input TextField

            textField = addChild(new TextField()) as TextField;
            textField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            textField.text = "Test Text";

            // Covers the TextField with a transparent shape

            var shape:Sprite = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;
            shape.graphics.beginFill(0, 0);
            shape.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, textField.width, textField.height);
            shape.mouseChildren = false;

            // Listens to a click on the mask to activate typing

            shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eventClickHandler);
        }

        private function eventClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Sets the focus to the underlaying TextField and makes 
            // a full selection of the existing text.

            stage.focus = textField;
            textField.setSelection(0, textField.text.length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with a custom [InteractiveObject.contextMenu](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#contextMenu)?

Answer (score 1):

Set the fields `selectable` property to false.

Comment: I want to keep it selectable to make CURSOR VISIBLE.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to hide the default context menu items for **TextFields**!

Just set a custom context menu, and hide the inbuilt items. Now when you right click, nothing happens!

```
 // hide cut/copy/paste
 var cm:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
 cm.hideBuiltInItems();
 textfield.contextMenu = cm;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for something like this everywhere! I will suggest the current best answer contains this solution as well.